# What is session?

Tags: session, authentication, token

I'm trying to build an user login and some of my friends told me about session and token. After hour searching on Google, I've still had no ideal about them.

I'm really appreciate if receiving any help!
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Technical difference between session and token based auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40862661/technical-difference-between-session-and-token-based-auth)

Answer (score 0):

To understand what a session is you should have idea of the client/server paradigm and how the HTTP protocol works. [MDN has a great guide that explains these things](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP).

A **session** begins when a server establishes a connection with a client. Commands are executed and transmitted between the two, then the connection is terminated. That is when the session ends.

It's basically the time when a server and client are interacting with each other.